# Duvida de como reverter valores em uma lista estatica em C

Tags: c, lista

Olá, estou com duvida em uma questão de um trabalho da universidade de como reverter uma sequencia de números em uma lista estática em C.
A parte em especifico que estou em duvida é :

```
**int SList_reverse(SList* lista, int dado){
      if(!SList_cheia(lista)){
      int i;
      for(i=0; i< lista->qty; i++)
        printf("<-[%d] ", lista->data[i]);
      putchar('\n');
      }
      return 0;
    }**
```

Código completo:

```
#include "StaticList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10
typedef struct list{
  int qty;
  int data[MAX];
} TList;

TList* SList_create(){
  TList* nova = (TList*) malloc(sizeof(TList));
  if(nova!=NULL){
    nova->qty = 0;
  }
  return nova;
}

int SList_insert(SList* lista, int dado){
  if(!SList_cheia(lista)){
    lista->data[(*lista).qty++] = dado;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void SList_print(SList* lista){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i< lista->qty; i++)
    printf("[%d]-> ", lista->data[i]);
  putchar('\n');
}

int SList_search(SList* lista, int dado){
  int i;
  for(i=lista->qty-1; i>=0; i--)
    if(lista->data[i] == dado)
      break;
  return i;
}

int SList_remove(SList* lista, int dado){
  if(!SList_vazia(lista)){
    int i = SList_search(lista, dado);
    if(i>=0){
      int j;
      for(j=i; j<lista->qty-1; j++){
        lista->data[j] = lista->data[j+1];
      }
      lista->qty--;
      return 1;
    }
  
  }
  return 0;
}

int SList_reverse(SList* lista, int dado){
  if(!SList_cheia(lista)){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i< lista->qty; i++)
    printf("<-[%d] ", lista->data[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}

void SList_destroy(SList* lista){
  if(lista!= NULL)
    free(lista);
}

int SList_getQty(SList* lista){
  if(lista!= NULL)
    return lista->qty;
  return 0;
}



int SList_cheia(SList* lista){
  return (lista->qty == MAX);
} 

int SList_vazia(SList* lista){
  return (lista->qty == 0);
}
```

Comment: Quando você diz `reverter uma sequencia de números`, você quer inverter a ordem dos número? Exmeplo: `123456789` em `987654321`.

Comment: Exatamente isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você nem precisa verificar se a lista está cheia, basta inverter os itens conforme o código abaixo.

```
int SList_reverse(SList* lista, int dado){
  int i;
  int aux;

  for(i=0; i< lista->qty /2; i++) {
    aux = lista->data[i];
    lista->data[i] = lista->data[(lista->qty - 1) - i];
    lista->data[lista->qty - i] = aux;
    printf("<-[%d] ", lista->data[(lista->qty - 1) - i]);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Repare que no seu código haverá um acesso a um local de memória fora do vetor da lista. Quando `i = 0`, então `lista->data[lista->qty - 0]`, considerando q o último elemento do vetor é `lista->data[lista->qty - 1]`, logo `lista->data[lista->qty - 0]` não faz parte do vetor. Isto é, se o tamanho for `10`, então o limite do vetor é `[9]`, logo `[10 - 0]` == `[10]`, que não é uma posição válida no vetor. Outro erro é que o `for` precisa repetir apenas metade das vezes que você colocou, pois quando chegar no meio ele vai desinverter o que foi invertido.

Comment: Teria que ser assim `lista->data[(lista->qty - 1) - i]` para corrigir o primeiro problema. O segundo basta colocar `i < (lista->qty / 2)` dentro do `for`

Comment: Verdade, postei correndo, as duas correções que você citou são necessárias.